# Writing a range loop to file

Tags: python

Below is my code, all I am trying to do is write to the file in the format that the code prints. I have tried all sorts and best I can get is the final number 17570 in the file. Clearly something wrong in the f.write , any suggestions ?

```
print("creating Table") 

nums = range(17501, 17570)
for i in range(0, len(nums),):
    print (nums[i],"1", "1" , "1" , "1")

F = open("new.txt" , "w")
f.write (nums[i], "1","1","1","1")
```

Answer (score 0):

try writing to file in one session.

```
with open('new.txt', 'a') as f:
    for i in range(0, len(nums),):
        f.write(str(nums[i]) + "1, 1, 1\n")
```

sorry for multiple edits but you can use `for n in nums:` statement instead of defining an index. so code below would be also valid and easier to understand:

```
with open("new.txt", "a") as f:
    for n in nums:
        f.write(str(n) + "1, 1, 1\n")
```

Comment: Ir is considered unpythonic to use range instead of directly accessing the variables as for x in y:

Comment: could you set this answer valid if this works for you?